# R program: I have a data in which I need to find the latest occurred time of an ID (this Id has duplicates)

Tags: r, duplicates, data-wrangling

IS there a way in R programming where I have a data in which I need to find the latest occurred time of an ID (this Id has duplicates). Below is the sample data and needed output.

Here is My code

```
mypath <-"C:/BO/ack_Off/Mac/Output/"
setwd(mypath)
filelist <- list.files(path=mypath, pattern="*.csv", full.names=FALSE)
filelist

library(tidyverse)

Almdata_3G <- map_dfr(filelist,read_csv,col_types = cols_only(Date = col_guess(),Action = col_guess(),Alm_id = col_guess(), Occur_time = col_guess()))
```

Almdata_3G :

```
  Date       Action Alm_id    Occur_time
-----------------------------------------------
01-06-2020  Insert  123457  6/1/2020 11:30:45
01-06-2020  Altered 123457  6/1/2020 11:35:45
01-06-2020  Altered 123457  6/1/2020 11:36:40
01-06-2020  Altered 123457  6/1/2020 11:35:40
01-06-2020  Altered 123457  6/1/2020 11:37:45
01-06-2020  Cleared 123457  6/1/2020 11:45:45
02-06-2020  Insert  123455  6/2/2020 00:15:25
02-06-2020  Altered 123455  6/2/2020 00:15:25
02-06-2020  Altered 123455  6/2/2020 00:25:15
02-06-2020  Altered 123455  6/2/2020 00:26:05
03-06-2020  Cleared 123455  6/3/2020 00:15:25
03-06-2020  Insert  123425  6/3/2020 14:15:25
03-06-2020  Cleared 123425  6/3/2020 16:15:25
03-06-2020  Altered 123425  6/3/2020 14:45:25
03-06-2020  Altered 123425  6/3/2020 14:12:25
03-06-2020  Insert  112625  6/3/2020 15:12:25
03-06-2020  Altered 112625  6/3/2020 16:12:25
03-06-2020  Altered 112625  6/3/2020 17:12:25
------------------------------------------------------
```

Output derived based on Individual Alm ids, and its Action (i.e. Insert -> First_Occur_time, latest Altered -> Last_Occur_time, cleared -> Cleared_Time). For this, initially, almid & Occur_time needs to be sorted ascending.

Output needed in another df:

```
 Date       Alm id   First_Occur_time    Last_Occur_time      Cleared_Time
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
01-06-2020  123457  6/1/2020 11:30:45   6/1/2020 11:37:45   6/1/2020 11:45:45
02-06-2020  123455  6/2/2020 00:15:25   6/2/2020 00:26:05   6/3/2020 00:15:25
03-06-2020  123425  6/3/2020 14:15:25   6/3/2020 14:45:25   6/3/2020 16:15:25
03-06-2020  112625  6/3/2020 15:12:25   6/3/2020 17:12:25
```

Kindly support over the R code & logic. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly doable in R, and there are many ways to go about it. It looks like you're showing us screenshots from Excel; have you already imported the data into R?

Comment: please do not post your data in [.NORM-format](https://xkcd.com/2116/).. ;-)

Comment: @Aaron: yes, I have imported the data into a df. kindly let me know, how can i achieve this logic. df name is "almdata"

Comment: Could you please make your dataset reproducible by editing your post and copying the results of `dput(almdata)`? If it's too long, you could instead copy `dput(head(almdata))` or `dput(head(almdata, 20))`. This will allow us to import your dataset into our R sessions and test the code for you.

Comment: Alternatively, you could put your sample data into R and give us a dput of that instead.

Comment: @Aaron, I have shared my code. I believe, you can see the data and required output in proper format, if you copy it to notepad.

Comment: The code you have provided is unfortunately still not reproducible; the first line of code references a directory that is specific to your computer. Is it possible for your to instead just give us the `dput()` of the relevant data frames from your own R sessions? This will eliminate problems like the one I just referenced.